# JAVA: Converting BigInteger to array of numbers

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a biginteger

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("2389623956378561348065123807561278905618906");
```

And I need to print all its digits (2, 3, 8, and so on...). How can I do it?

Comment: Why not just `toString()` it and loop through the String?

Comment: What´s wrong with `System.out.println(b)`?

Comment: Your title says you want to convert it to an array of "numbers" and in your question you say that you want to print it. What is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Evan Knowles Very interesting. Thanks for the hint. It helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered by [Evan Knowles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137269/evan-knowles) and [user3322273](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3322273/user3322273), but here is another implementation:

```
byte[] digits = b.getBytes();
for (byte digit : digits) {
    System.out.println (digit & 0xf);
}
```

What it does is that it *masks* the (ASCII) value of the digit. For example:

```
'0' = 48     | In ASCII and Unicode - Decimal
    = 110000 | In binary
```

Hence, if we obtain the **last four bits**, then we can get the number. So

```
48 & 0xf (i.e. 15)
= 11 0000
& 00 1111
=    0000
=    0   | Ultimately in decimal.
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert to char array, then decrease from each char the ASCII code of '0' char, to get digits between 0 and 9

```
char[] digits = b.toString().toCharArray();
for (char digit : digits) {
    digit -= '0';
    System.out.println((int)digit);
}
```

Note that if you just want to print, don't reduce the '0' ASCII value, and don't cast to `int` when printing